# What is the best way to take backups in memsql cluster?

Tags: singlestore

What is the best way to take backups of memsql cluster?

I will be using enterprise memsql, is backup command of memsql better or mysqldump/rsync better to take backups ?

Answer (score 1):

The BACKUP command https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/backup/ has several advantages compared to mysqldump or rsync - it is much faster, due to being parallelized (unlike mysqldump) and a physical instead of logical backup, and it provides a consistent transactional snapshot.